# Google maps: Drag the circle only when I click on center and drag

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Map v3 and I have 2 issues.

1)
I am drawing a circle on the maps that is draggable
According to the documentation,when draggable is set to true the circle can be dragged when i click anywhere inside the circle and drag but i want it to move only when i click on the CENTER and drag.How to do this?

2)How to place a custom icon on the center of the circle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put a marker at the center of the circle, make that draggable and bind the center of the circle to it.

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map:map,
    center: map.getCenter(),
    radius: 5000
});
var currMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    draggable: true,
    icon: { url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle_blue.png",
           size: new google.maps.Size(7,7),
           anchor: new google.maps.Point(4,4)
          },
    map:map
});
circle.bindTo('center', currMarker, 'position');
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vMY36/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.606209, -122.332069)
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    center: map.getCenter(),
    radius: 5000
  });
  var currMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    draggable: true,
    icon: {
      url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle_blue.png",
      size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(4, 4)
    },
    map: map
  });
  circle.bindTo('center', currMarker, 'position');

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id='map-canvas'></div>
```